# How to get back to manager level in Team Drive I created?

Tags: permissions, google-shared-drive

I created a Google Team Drive and automatically became a manager. Then I lowered down my level to content manager.

I realized that I can't add or delete members since I lost my qualification as a manager level.

How can I get back to manager level so I can add or delete members?

Comment: @Glorfindel on this site [tag:permissions] is a meta-tag and as such, it should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know. I only tried to be complete and not just fix the grammar in the post. It might be worthwhile adding that information in the tag wiki excerpt, though [this Meta question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3977) has been removed ...

Answer (score 0):

Ask for help to your G Suite admin or to another user this manager level access.